# How to interprete the Locust results

Tags: request, response, load-testing, stress-testing, locust

I am running a stress test for a particular website from my CPU with about 20 workers and getting the below results

[image]

However, I see that the Average response time is too high and is increasing with the number of requests and users. What might be the reason for such high numbers when the actual response time is very less. By any chance, do I need to divide it by the number of requests?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason for this is that the system you are testing is overloaded, there is probably nothing wrong with your test or Locust itself.

How to fix this entirely depedent on what the problem in your system is (locust cant really help you with that), but there are a few pointers here: https://github.com/locustio/locust/wiki/FAQ#increase-my-request-raterps

> By any chance, do I need to divide it by the number of requests?

No

Comment: Thanks. Any by system, you mean the CPU or the web server?

Comment: Could be cpu, could be network bandwidth, web server configuration, or something else entirely. There's no way of knowing without looking "under the hood" of your system. The load generation tool can only see the response times, which can be impacted by a number of things.

Comment: Hey, I noticed something in your screenshot: Your user count is very high. Unless you also have high wait times or sleeps in your tests, >3000 users is enough to break most systems.